# spring boot 2.0.3 oauth2 authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I have the following configuration

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-jose', version: '5.0.6.RELEASE'
```

A simple sprint boot app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the client configs

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=x
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=y
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-id=x
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.client-secret=y
```

After checking a few resources and the spring security oauth2 docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-oauth2login I am expecting that all this code will configure the application as an @EnableWebFlux with @EnableWebFluxSecurity and will configure the default ClientRepository with the clients provided in properties file.

They say when you access your app you will get a list with the clients you added. Instead I receive a basic authentication mechanism. Any idea what is happening or am I doing something wrong?